# Over-ride javascript function in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have JavaScript function named GetUserData which has call function reference.

Signature for GetUserData  is as follows.

```
function GetUserData(callback)
{
  // do something
}
```

I,m calling it as  below.

```
function LoginSuccess()
{
  // do something   
}

 GetUserData(LoginSuccess());
```

Now as this function is master page , In each page I want to do something different on LoginSuccess.

```
function LoginSuccess()
    {
      // do something else. 
    }
```

can this be done?

Comment: yes, simply put the `LoginSuccess` function in the page and put `GetUserData` in the master page

Comment: @Manish Remember that new function should load later then default, so that new function override the old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can Override Java script functions.
But the function with same signature loaded in the last will override all other function of same signature.

**Example**

```
function mytest(param1)
{
 alert(1);
}

function mytest(param1)
{
 alert(2);
}
```

The above will alert 2, as this function was loaded last.

In your case  intial method should be loaded in the heder part of master page(in case of external file.) and in the content page load your override function in the body or somewhere in such a sequence that it will be loaded after the master page method.